# Gmail automatic canned responses with external SMTP server

Tags: gmail, gmail-canned-response

Gmail allows users to filter e-mails based on many things such as words, sender, etc. and once matched it can auto-reply each filtered email with a canned response (requires Canned Responses lab], among other actions. Those replies seem to be necessarily sent from the Gmail address of the account doing the filtering and they include a +canned.response or +auto.reply "tag" in the email address.

Is there any "easy" way (even if another 3rd party service or a Unix server is needed) to send those auto-canned-responses from some external SMTP server as it is possible to do when sending manual replies from Gmail web app?

<sub>By doing so we could use -for example- a more corporate-style email address such as `reply@mycompany.com` instead of `myaccount+canned.response@gmail.com`</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this is easy to do on any UNIX system with [procmail](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue14/procmail.html) for example.  For more of a service-desk type approach, I know [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/) supports auto-responses, and I'm sure many of the other issue tracking systems (JIRA, BugZilla, etc) do the same.  The question becomes, do you just need to send a response, or do you want all of the functionality of the issue tracking system as well.